Not able to execute before_all and after_all method only once
I'm running my tests in parallel using 4 processes - scenario by scenario.
I want to do some tasks in before_all and after_all but only 1 time, meaning do X in before_all only 1 time and use X in after_all only 1 time
I tried to use context.config.userdata['worker_id'], current_process(), parent_process() in order to identify but instances are totally different.
Please suggest me some solution or a workaround which I can try to achieve it

implement shared resource or locking mechanism that ensures these setup and teardown function execute only once per testing session

I tried this using threading.Event() and threading.Lock()  but since I'm using behavex it running the instances all in parallel

you can use file baed lock with fcntl or shared platform like multiprocessing.manager or the other solution is shared database or Redis
